# RX, Loaded event

Tags: system.reactive

Attempting to use RX with events, but this one is alluding me.  This is the "normal" way to subscribe to an event

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SelectPartyPersonDataEntry_Loaded);
```

The RX Way....

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(this, "Loaded").Subscribe((routedEvent) => this.Searchbutton_Click(routedEvent.Sender, routedEvent.EventArgs));
```

however, it fails silently and I'm not sure why.

Thanks!

---

I'm not quite sure how to handle this, as both of these answers helped me understand where I was going wrong with this.  The correct syntax (or that one that works is):

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(h => this.Loaded += h, h => this.Loaded -= h).Subscribe(routedEvents => SelectPartyPersonDataEntry_Loaded(routedEvents.Sender, routedEvents.EventArgs));
```

Which simply looks more confusing that anything else.  I have to provide both the EventHandler type (RoutedEventHandler), as well as the event argument type to (RoutedEventArgs), in order to subscribe to the events.  Using this signature of the FromEventPattern means that I have to have use the +=/-= syntax subscribing to the event.

I only see one reason why you would do this over the traditional (and more concise) syntax - the difference between a strong reference, and a weak reference.  If this View goes out of scope, you must ensure the strong reference in order for the view to be garbadge collected (GC).  The RX syntax is a weak reference, and as such will be GC without the dereferencing the event.

Comment: I assume that you're not actually intending to subscribe to events in this way???

Comment: and your reasons for not doing so?

Comment: @codputer - If you're using standard event handler methods then just use the standard event handler syntax. Using `FromEventPattern` allows you so much more power - you can capture variables, filter, project, zip, compose queries, etc. You use Rx to get away from standard event handling - don't use it to go backwards. Does that make sense?

Comment: Robert - ahhh - ok - but you DELETED the answer.  How does that help the community? I've upvoted both the responses, as per your suggestion, but neither is the answer.  Not sure how you think that your actions is the right thing to do for the community.  Please re-instate it and then I will then mark it as the answer.

Comment: @codputer - Based on your edit I think you're missing the point of Rx. It's about the querying, composition and asynchrony. Can you let us know what you're really trying to achieve and maybe we can give you a better application of Rx to illustrate the point.

Comment: @codputer your answer wasn't an answer, but an expansion on your question. In those situations, just edit your question, rather than posting your question as an answer. This is what will benefit the community. This has already been done for you, I just wanted to explain Robert's deletion to you.

Comment: @codputer: as to your second question, the reason for getting events into an observable is not because of the syntax, but more of the combinatorics you can do one that observable once you have it like that. When dealing with Rx, the goal isn't listening to events, the goal is being able to combine, filter, aggregate, and generally make any event or set of events into a complex state machine with very little code. I would suggest perhaps watching a few intro videos, like this excellent one: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/codefest/DC2010T0100-Keynote-Rx-curing-your-asynchronous-programming-blues

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this in a WPF app:

```
var loadedEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern(this, "Loaded");
loadedEvent.Subscribe(e => MessageBox.Show("loaded"));
```

And it works; the message box is shown.

Perhaps you could elaborate what you mean when you say it fails silently -- have you tried this in a debugger? Are you sure there's a Loaded event in there?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is Silverlight, and that loaded event has the event handler of a "RoutedEventHandler" which requires a delegate of "delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);" Note that in your example, you use the EventArgs rather than RoutedEventArgs... something that I did not notice until now.

Comment: My guess, then, is that your handler syntax is wrong. Verify your handler handles the right kind of event arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it has something to do with not providing the type of the event args. The method signature that you're using is:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>>
    FromEventPattern(object target, string eventName)
```

I suspect you need:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<TEventArgs>>
    FromEventPattern<TEventArgs>(object target, string eventName)
    where TEventArgs: EventArgs
```

Better yet, don't use the "reflection" method (i.e. no magic strings). Use this instead:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<TEventArgs>>
    FromEventPattern<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
        Action<TDelegate> addHandler, Action<TDelegate> removeHandler)
    where TEventArgs: EventArgs
```